# Function from script editor works fine but not from sheets custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, google-calendar-api, custom-function

I wrote a function that adds an all-day event.

When the function running from script editor it's working fine, the all-day event is inserted to the calendar.

But when I'm running the function in the active spreadsheet `=addevent(a1,b1,c1,d1)`

I'm getting an error saying :

> Exception: The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly || https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds) (line 11)

After searching the net I found how to add manually those permission by editing the `oauthScopes` in the JSON file:

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
    "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    
  ],
  
  "timeZone": "censored",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Calendar",
      "serviceId": "calendar",
      "version": "v3"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
  


}
```

But I am still getting the same error in the spreadsheet...

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*While it is not possible to run a script which requires authorisation directly from a cell in a Sheet, you can set up the script to run on button click instead.*

#### More Information & Workaround:

As a button does not have the same [authorisation restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced) as custom functions, you can use them to run code with the scopes you need. To set this up:

1. Go to the `Insert > Drawing` menu item and create a shape; any shape will do, this will act as your button.
2. Press `Save and Close` to add this to your sheet.
3. Move the newly-added drawing to where you would like. In the top-right of the drawing, you will see the vertical ellipsis menu (`⋮`). Click this, and then click `Assign script`.
4. In the new window, type whatever the name of your function is, without parentheses (for example `myFunction`), and press `OK`.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are not allowed to use a custom function to perform actions that require **authorization** such as adding an event to your calendar.

From the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced):

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask
> users to authorize access to personal data.

However, there are some workarounds that you could try. For example, you can create a custom menu option within your spreadsheet file or a time-driven trigger.