# Wrapper around importdata() in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to write a wrapper around Google Sheets' `importdata()` in `code.gs`:

```
100 
101  function cryptofinance(token) {
102     var currentCell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
103     currentCell.setValue('=importdata("https://cryptoprices.cc/"+ token)');
104  }
105
106 ...
```

The idea is to call the function from any sheet in the spreadsheet to get the price of any crypto currency token:

```
    |          A
+---+-------------------------+
| 1 |  =cryptofinance("aion") |
+---+-------------------------+
```

I get an error though when I try this:

```
    |          A
+---+-------------------------+
| 1 |  #ERROR                 |
+---+-------------------------+
```

`#ERROR Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action. (line 102).`

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: What it's the purpose of building a "wrapper" instead of using IMPORTDATA directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom functions can be used to return values, period.

Custom function  can't be used to execute any method that require authorization to run and can't modify attributes of the cell / range that contain the formula using the custom function. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

You might use a UrlFetchApp service in a custom function to call external services but you still have the restrictions of custom function i.e. 30 seconds execution time limit.

Related

- [Function from script editor works fine but not from sheets custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63555316/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
function cryptofinance(token = "AION") {
 //Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://cryptoprices.cc/${token}/`));
 return UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://cryptoprices.cc/${token}/`).getContentText();
}
```

Comment: The methods getContent and getContentText both provide results.  I don't know which you want.  Using caps for the token seems to be necessary

Answer (score -1):

Some permissions are assumed by Apps Scripts when running functions but in some instances you need to update your `appsscripts.json` with the correct OAuth permissions manually to give permission to access data.

To show your `appsscripts.json`, navigate to your project settings and toggle the option "Show 'appsscript.json' manifest file in editor". This should reveal it in the sidebar in Apps Scripts.

Once in the `appsscript.json`, add

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
 ]
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes)